# Trial Experiance in Windows Phone 8 app

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I need to create trial experience in my WP8 app. What i want to clarify is that when i use the LicenseInformation.IsTrial() method in Release mode in the Emulator it returns false as in the app is in Full mode. Is this correct? And when i use this LicenseInformation.IsTrial() method should i always check to see if the internet connectivity is available before calling the method. What happens if i don't check for internet connectivity when the app is in the market? What value will it return then? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the `IsTrial` method always returns false when you are running in the emulator. have alook at [How to: Test and Debug Your Trial Application for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff967557%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) on MSDN for how to debug your trial application.

Internet connectivity is not required, WP manages the whole trial thing for you. I wonder where you heard about this.

Comment: What i want to know is that, what happens when the app is in the store and user downloads it as a trial. When the app checks to see if it is trial and i don;t check to make sure that internet is available will IsTrial() method throw an Exception? if not what will happen?

Comment: The user downloads the app as a trial and then IsTrial returns true - it doesn't matter whether the user has an internet connection or not. Internet is only required when the user decides to pay for your app. At least that's what it's like with my own trial app.

Comment: Is the trial status stored within the phone it self? I thought the trial status is taken by connecting to the Store.

Comment: Yes, it is stored on the device. Only when changing the trial status (initial download or when buying), WP requires internet.

Comment: Thanks a lot bro, Got the answer i required.